# C++ segmentation fault in a for loop during the entry in the loop

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I write a print function inside a class and a segmentation fault appears.

```
        void print() {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
            parents[i]->print();
        }
    }
```

parents is an array of pointers to parent objects. The parent parent object print is:

```
    void print() const{
    int i;
    std::cout << "Desired teachers:" << tnumb << std::endl;
    for(i=0; i<tnumb; i++){
        std::cout << "Teachers number:" << teachers[i] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

and I have confirmed it works if I make a new parent in my main and then call it. What is intrensting is that if I write printq as this:

```
        void print() {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
            std::cout << "ok\t";
        }
    }
```

no segmentation fault will appear and there will be as many ok as expected (counter btw is a type int which counts the number of items in the parents array). But if I write it like this:

```
        void print() {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
            std::cout << "ok\t";
            parents[i]->print();
        }
    }
```

not a single ok is printed and a segmentation fault appears. I cannot understand why even the first cout isn't executed.

Sorry if my code is too generic. I tried to keep the essentials because it is still messy and it is easy to get lost.

Here is the class's constructor:

```
queue(int _size): start(0), end(0), current(0), size(_size), counter(0){
        parents = new parent *[size];
    }
```

And a parent is inserted in the parents with this push function:

```
        void push(parent *p){
        if(p->get_done()){
            return;
        }
        p->set_start();
        if(p->enter_start()){
            std::cout << "*Entire line boos*\n";
        }
        if(!full()){
            end++;
            counter++;
            parents[end] = p;
        }else{
            std::cout << "Parents queue is full\n";
        }
    }
```

The set_start and the line booing are working and have no actual effect on the parent (it is just a senario with a simple flag where it will either trigger the cout or not). Counter offers the number of items inserted up to this point while end is an int that gives the last used spot in the queue.

The message **parents queue is full** doesn't appear so the parents[end] must contain parent p.

In case any more information is needed please comment and I will edit it

Comment: Try flushing the `cout` stream after each `std::cout << "ok\t";` to see the first `ok`.

Comment: How are you filling your `parents`? You've shown us the constructor (ok) but they're raw, uninitialised pointers. You need to be initialising them somewhere (and if you aren't, then it justifies the segfault).

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that you are trying to call print() on a null pointer.

```
parents[i]->print();
```

in the above code `parents[i]` is likely null.

You can do a simple test before accessing `parents[i]`, like this:

```
if (parents[i] != NULL) {
    parents[i]->print();
} else {
    std::cout << " parents[" << i << "] was null!" << std::endl;
}
```

also like mentioned by TrebuchetMS in their comment above you can flush cout to make sure everything gets printed despite a segmentation fault. So I would suggest this as your final code to help you debug:

```
void print() {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
        std::cout << "ok\t";
        cout.flush();
        if (parents[i] != NULL) {
            parents[i]->print();
        } else {
            std::cout << "parents[" << i << "] was null!" << std::endl;
            cout.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

This won't help you find out why `parents[i]` is null but will prove that it is. The next step is to find out why it's null, and for this we need to see more of your code.

Happy debugging!

Comment: I think OP is not initializing the pointers at all he creates, which may or may not point to NULL. Also `std::cerr` can be used to flush input automatically every time `operator<<` is called. Good first answer, though!

Comment: Also note: `nullptr` is preferred over `NULL` (for pointers, at least).

Comment: @GillBates Thanks! Also, I've never used `std::cerr` before but will give it a shot as it sounds more convenient than `std::cout` with flushing!

Comment: I also included the push function if it helps but I'll have to check your notes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the error thanks to a7ger's help in debugging. Apparently I was trying to access a NULL pointers members. I was doing 
`end++` and then `parents[end] = p` while I should be doing the opposite. Thanks for the help